# Usage of Passive Voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Recently, I got an internship as a Content Writer, and they issue a report for the work done using Grammarly for further corrections before finalizing. I have noticed that a lot of the suggested changes by Grammarly were of usage of passive voice.

How do I avoid this to begin with and why is considered wrong?

Comment: Like spellcheck, Grammarly may help but doesn't deserve the final say. You do. If interning means training-by-AI, that's the tail wagging the dog.

Comment: Passive voice is traditionally used in technical reports.  Instead of constantly repeating "I did this ... " or "We found ..." or "The Lab implemented ...", just mention once at the beginning who is doing all the stuff, then put the rest in passive.  Some egomaniacs may want to mention themselves in every sentence, but generally that is considered bad form.

Comment: *How do I avoid this to begin with* You mean avoid using the passive, or avoid getting a warning from Grammarly (without changing your writing)?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you, I you can give some examples of uses that Grammarly 'thinks' are wrong.  Could you give two or three examples?